# How to fix missing CR in Console App Display

Tags: c#, powershell, console

I have written a console application in C# that uses Console.Writeline to output text.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Test Results Failures: {failures.Count}");
Console.WriteLine($"             System Errors: {systemErrors.Count}");
```

When executed via Powershell, the output shown via Powershell is

```
Test Results  Failures: 14                         System Errors: 13
```

Note the lack of carriage returns.

How do I fix this?

I am invoking the Powershell Script from Powershell command line:

```
powershell -noexit "& 'RunAndTest.ps1'"
```

And the script:

```
$output="`n------------Tests ---------------`n"
Write-Host $output;

$output="-------> Running Postman"
Write-Host $output;

$collection='collection.json';
$environment='local_environment.json';
$output=$(newman run $collection -e $environment --color off --disable-unicode);

Write-Host $output;

$output="-------> Evaluating Results`n"
Write-Host $output;

$output=$(dotnet FunctionalTestXml.dll test.xml);
Write-Host $output;

If ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
    $output= "Success"
} Else {
    $output = "Failure " + $LastExitCode
}

Write-Host $output;

$output="`n---------------------------------`n"

Write-Host $output;
```

The console app is executed via the dotnet command:

```
$output=$(dotnet FunctionalTestXml.dll test.xml);
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: From an interactive PowerShell session, this shouldn't happen. Please edit your question to show how, specifically, you're invoking PowerShell and specifics about versions involved, console (terminal) application used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems related to whether or not a result is used:

```
$output=$(dotnet FunctionalTestXml.dll test.xml);
Write-Host $output;
```

Is problematic. Just doing

```
dotnet FunctionalTestXml.dll test.xml
```

Displays properly.

I don't understand why the CR-LF are lost. This condition is manifesting itself in other scenarios as well, e.g., evaluating the result from another PS script.

```
$result = & "RunAndTest.ps1"
#display script output
Write-Host $result
```

Results in CR-LF lost as well.

Answer (score -2):

You could do

```
Console.WriteLine("Test Results Failures: " + failures.Count);
Console.WriteLine("             System Errors: " + systemErrors.Count);
```

Comment: How does this fix the missing CR/LF problem?

Comment: Well, I tested your code and it works ok. It's unclear from your question what else you could be doing wrong, so I gave you a snippet which is functionaly identical to what you have but who knows, maybe it works for you. Like I said try to be more explicit and detailed about what is happening to you, maybe show the full code and how you invoke the program from the shell.

Comment: @Steve isn't the OP. I agree with him (I'm not the OP either). In the absence of knowing what the true problem is, posting a functionally equivalent solution that can't reasonably be expected to make a difference not only doesn't help, it creates a distraction.